# How to install StarUML and it's dependencies?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and want to install StarUML. I downloaded StarUML from http://staruml.io/download/release/v2.0.2/StarUML-v2.0.2-64-bit.deb, then in the terminal:

```
dpkg -i StarUML-v2.0.2-64-bit.deb
```

I got this message:

```
Unpacking staruml (2.0.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of staruml:
staruml depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5); however:
Package libgcrypt11 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package staruml (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
staruml
```

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 9):

You can download and install the libgcrypt11 package from Precise and Trust Ubuntu repositories, for example:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i StarUML-v2.8.0-64-bit.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

The StarUML package has a couple of dependencies:

```
Depends: gconf-service,
 libasound2 (>= 1.0.23),
 libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4),
 libc6 (>= 2.11),
 libcairo2 (>= 1.6.0),
 libcups2 (>= 1.4.0),
 libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.2.14),
 libexpat1 (>= 1.95.8),
 libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0),
 libfreetype6 (>= 2.3.9),
 libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1),
 libgconf-2-4 (>= 2.31.1),
 libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5),
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0),
 libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.18.0),
 libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0),
 libnspr4 (>= 1.8.0.10),
 libnss3 (>= 3.12.6),
 libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0),
 libstdc++6 (>= 4.6),
 libudev0 (>= 147) | libudev1 (>= 198),
 libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1),
 libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1),
 libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1),
 libxext6, libxfixes3,
 libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.2.0),
 libxrender1,
 ca-certificates,
 libcurl3,
 lsb-base (>= 3.2),
 xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2),
 wget
```

Some of these are trivial and should be found on most desktop installations.

If you install them using:

```
sudo apt-get install ./StarUML-v2.0.2-64-bit.deb
```

apt-get will find and install the dependencies automatically.

Now, the specific package that is lacking "libgcrypt11" is only available on Precise and Trust (12.04 and 14.04)][1](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/madison.cgi?package=libgcrypt11&a=&c=&s=), it was replaced with libgcrypt20 by Debian, and therefore Ubuntu.

I would contact the package maintainer of the package , you can find out who they are with this command

```
dpkg --info StarUML-v2.0.2-64-bit.deb | grep Maintainer
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The above commands should fix dependencies issues installing missing packages that your program need.

You can get more information about apt-get command reading the manual:

```
man apt-get
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case it proposed to remove starUML but does not install the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

First download libgcrypt package: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb

Then install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
```

Finally, install StarUML:

```
sudo dpkg -i StarUML-v2.7.0-64-bit.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

First download libgcrypt package from below link:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb

Then open terminal with location where above file is saved and  install it by below command:

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
```

Now download starUML from below link:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/staruml-bucket/releases-v2/StarUML-v2.8.1-64-bit.deb

Then open terminal with location where your above file is saved and install it by below command:

```
sudo dpkg -i StarUML-v2.8.0-64-bit.deb
```

Comment: Downloading .deb packages from random AWS S3 buckets to install as root is an exceptionally dangerous idea. Why would someone get the software from that bucket instead of the official project page?