# Installing StarUML 2.8 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

I am trying to install StarUML 2.8 from the [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/staruml-bucket/releases-v2/StarUML-v2.8.1-64-bit.deb) in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
The package requires "libcurl3". When I install it, it removes the packages "cmake" and "libcurl4". How can I install StarUML (2.8) without removing cmake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here exists better solution - you can user AppImage from [official site](http://staruml.io/download), it has newer 3.0.1 version:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://staruml.io/download/releases/StarUML-3.0.1-x86_64.AppImage
chmod +x StarUML-3.0.1-x86_64.AppImage
./StarUML-3.0.1-x86_64.AppImage
```

---

About exact 2.8.1 version - I tested the solution below (based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/853242/66509)) and my ideas.

```
#1. download StarUML package and its dependencies
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/staruml-bucket/releases-v2/StarUML-v2.8.1-64-bit.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/udev/libudev0_175-7.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libudev0_175-7.2_amd64.deb

#2. install StarUML dependencies but without `libcurl3`
sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 \
libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgcc1 \
libgconf-2-4 libgcrypt11 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0  \
libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libstdc++6 libudev0 libx11-6 libxcomposite1  \
libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxrandr2 libxrender1 ca-certificates \
lsb-base xdg-utils wget

#3. create folder for locally installed Software and StarUML
mkdir ~/Software ; cd ~/Software
mkdir StarUML ; cd StarUML

#3.1. extract StarUML here
dpkg -x ~/Downloads/StarUML-v2.8.1-64-bit.deb .

#3.2. add this folder to the PATH variable in ~/.bashrc
echo "PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/Software/StarUML/opt/staruml" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

#3.3. edit launcher file to reflect the path and add it to menu
cd opt/staruml/
sed -i "s/^Exec=\/opt\/staruml\/staruml\ %U/Exec=\/home\/$USER\/Software\/StarUML\/opt\/staruml\/staruml %U/" staruml.desktop
sed -i "s/^Icon=staruml/Icon=\/home\/$USER\/Software\/StarUML\/usr\/share\/icons\/hicolor\/scalable\/apps\/staruml.svg/" staruml.desktop
chmod +x staruml.desktop
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/
ln -s /home/$USER/Software/StarUML/opt/staruml/staruml.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/staruml.desktop
```

When all these steps done you will be able to launch application from dash by *StarUML* shortcut or from terminal with `staruml` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would like to have the solution for StarUML 2.8 without affecting cake!

Comment: Edited, you can try new working solution for v.2.8.1.

Comment: The AppImage doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Any .deb file can be installed via a single command...    `sudo dpkg -i < .deb file >`

Comment: more on the subject:   https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_dpkg_installation/